# How to remove this $.getScript("https://activeitzone.com/check/larashop.js") from ACTIVE IT ZONE

Tags: php, laravel

this making problem creating API
this script files attached to every single page in laravel view but unable to 
find it by a search.
also append to API please help to remove it

```
{
    "fail": "Wrong Credentials"
}
```

$(function(){$.getScript("https://activeitzone.com/check/larashop.js");
    });$(function(){$.getScript("https://activeitzone.com/check/larashop.js");
    });

Comment: If you're using linux or Mac, try `grep -R larashop *` from the root of your project to see where that script is in your files.

Comment: Please put your javascript code inside a code block

Comment: no, I have already tried searching but not found. script maybe encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you Open file: vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php

Remove content: public function _string_header($header). $_string_header =